# How can I give free access to anyone on the sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I would like everyone, no matter if they have a microsoft account, if they are logged in or if they have an invitation, visit the website. Like any internet site, just open the link and the site appears.

[website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2bPM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. SharePoint Online Public Websites feature is not supported by Microsoft anymore. Please refer to this article for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/public-websites-be-discontinued

> Beginning May 1, 2017, anonymous access for existing sites will no
> longer be available. If customers need more time to move their public
> website, they have a one-time postponement option for up to one year
> (March 31, 2018). Customers must select the postpone option by May 1,
> 2017.

Comment: Michael, thanks to helpe me.
But, this:
https://www.caixa.gov.br/Paginas/home-caixa.aspx
 is a bank website here in Brazil, and I was informed that it was developed on the sharepoint. But I still don't understand how it can be accessed even though public access is no longer supported

Comment: That site is developed on the SharePoint Server. SharePoint online and SharePoint server  are different. SharePoint Server is a locally-hosted platform that your company owns and operates. While SharePoint Online is a cloud-based service provided directly from Microsoft. Only SharePoint Server support anonymous access.